# I can't seem to figure out why my score function is working, any idea?

Tags: javascript

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#remaining-time").hide();
    $("#start").on('click', trivia.startGame);
    $(document).on('click', '.option', trivia.guessChecker);
})

var trivia = {
    correct: 0,
    incorrect: 0,
    unanswered: 0,
    points: 0,
    currentSet: 0,
    timer: 20,
    timerOn: false,
    timerId: '',
    questions: {
        q1: "According to Greek mythology, who stole fire for mankind's benefit?",
        q2: "Name the Chinese game played with small tiles.",
        q3: "In Japanese, what is the word for goodbye?",
        q4: "What nationality of soldiers wear a white kilt?",
        q5: "Leonardo da Vinci was born in what country?",
        q6: "Mount Fuji is the highest mountain in what conutry?",
        q7: "In terms of land area, what is the largest country in the world?",
        q8: "Adidas and Volkswagen are companies from what country?",
        q9: "The Channel Tunnel links England with which European country?",
        q10: "Adolf Hitler was born in what country?",
        q11: "Portugal is bordered by only what country?",
        q12: "India Ink was developed in what country?",
        q13: "Which fictional city is the home of Batman?",
        q14: "In which sport would you perform the Fosbury Flop?",
        q15: "Spinach is high in which mineral?"
    },
    options: {
        q1: ["Prometheus", "Hercules", "Zeus", "Odysseus"],
        q2: ["Go", "Sudoku", "Mah-Jong", "Pai Gow"],
        q3: ["Arigato", "Sayonara", "Konnichiwa", "Domo"],
        q4: ["Scottish", "Greek", "French", "German"],
        q5: ["Italy", "France", "Greece", "Great Britian"],
        q6: ["Arigato", "Sayonara", "Konnichiwa", "Domo"],
        q7: ["United States", "China", "Australia", "Russia"],
        q8: ["Russia", "Italy", "Germany", "Mexico"],
        q9: ["France", "Greece", "Italy", "Spain"],
        q10: ["Germany", "Austria", "Russia", "Switzerland"],
        q11: ["Austria", "Sweden", "China", "Spain"],
        q12: ["China", "India", "Vietnam", "Italy"],
        q13: ["Gotham", "New York", "Brooklyn", "Miami"],
        q14: ["Long Jump", "High Jump", "Soccer", "Football"],
        q15: ["Coal", "Gold", "Bronze", "Iron"]
    },
    answers: {
        q1: "Prometheus",
        q2: "Mah-Jong",
        q3: "Sayonara",
        q4: "Greek",
        q5: "Italy",
        q6: "Sayonara",
        q7: "Russia",
        q8: "Germany",
        q9: "France",
        q10: "Austria",
        q11: "Spain",
        q12: "China",
        q13: "Gotham",
        q14: "High Jump",
        q15: "Iron"
    },
    startGame: function() {
        trivia.currentSet = 0;
        trivia.correct = 0;
        trivia.incorrect = 0;
        trivia.unanswered = 0;
        trivia.points = 0;
        clearInterval(trivia.timerId);
        $('#game').show();
        $('#results').html('');
        $('#timer').text(trivia.timer);
        $('#start').hide();
        $('#remaining-time').show();
        trivia.nextQuestion();
    },
    nextQuestion: function() {
        trivia.timer = 10;
        $('#timer').removeClass('last-seconds');
        $('#timer').text(trivia.timer);
        if (!trivia.timerOn) {
            trivia.timerId = setInterval(trivia.timerRunning, 1000);
        }
        var questionContent = Object.values(trivia.questions)[trivia.currentSet];
        $('#question').text(questionContent);
        var questionOptions = Object.values(trivia.options)[trivia.currentSet];
        $.each(questionOptions, function(index, key) {
            $('#options').append($('<button class="option btn btn-info btn-lg">' + key + '</button>'));
        })
    },
    timerRunning: function() {
        if (trivia.timer > -1 && trivia.currentSet < Object.keys(trivia.questions).length) {
            $('#timer').text(trivia.timer);
            trivia.timer--;
            if (trivia.timer === 4) {
                $('#timer').addClass('last-seconds');
            }
        } else if (trivia.timer === -1) {
            trivia.unanswered++;
            trivia.result = false;
            clearInterval(trivia.timerId);
            resultId = setTimeout(trivia.guessResult, 1000);
            $('#results').html('<h3>Out of time! The answer was ' + Object.values(trivia.answers)[trivia.currentSet] + '</h3>');
        } else if (trivia.currentSet === Object.keys(trivia.questions).length) {
            $('#results')
                .html('<h3>Thank you for playing!</h3>' +
                    '<p>Correct: ' + trivia.correct + '</p>' +
                    '<p>Incorrect: ' + trivia.incorrect + '</p>' +
                    '<p>Unaswered: ' + trivia.unanswered + '</p>' +
                    '<h3>Score: ' + trivia.points + '</h3>');
            $('#game').hide();
            $('#start').show();
        }
    },
    guessChecker: function() {
        var resultId;
        var currentAnswer = Object.values(trivia.answers)[trivia.currentSet];
        if ($(this).text() === currentAnswer) {
            $(this).addClass('btn-success').removeClass('btn-info');
            trivia.correct++;
            clearInterval(trivia.timerId);
            resultId = setTimeout(trivia.guessResult, 1000);
            $('#results').html('<h3>Correct Answer!</h3>');
        } else {
            $(this).addClass('btn-danger').removeClass('btn-info');
            trivia.incorrect++;
            clearInterval(trivia.timerId);
            resultId = setTimeout(trivia.guessResult, 1000);
            $('#results').html('<h3>Incorrect! The correct answer is: ' + currentAnswer + '</h3>');
        }
    },
    updateScore: function() {
        if ($(this).text() === currentAnswer) {
            $(this).addClass('btn-success').removeClass('btn-info');
            trivia.points++;
            trivia.points * 100;
        }
    },
    guessResult: function() {
        trivia.currentSet++;
        $('.option').remove();
        $('#results h3').remove();
        trivia.nextQuestion();
    }
}
```

Currently trying to figure out why my score function doesn't work. It just suppose to update the points at the end of the game, just like it updates the number of correct answers and incorrect answers. Except the score will be 100 times however many correct answers they got. Everything works except for the points. Can anyone help point out what probably small detail I probably missed?

Comment: Please give a [mcve] with an emphasis on "minimal". Don't just dump a wall of code on Stack Overflow and hope that we will debug it for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not using the value from the expression `trivia.points * 100;`.  You need to actually assign the value using an assignment operator:

```
trivia.points = trivia.points * 100;
```

Or more succinctly:

```
trivia.points *= 100;
```

Although, doing this on every correct answer is likely not going to be what you want.